# Filter and search unordered list Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, html-lists

I'm looking for a way to filter an unordered list using an input field with angular.

I have a component which builds an unordered list on page load with data fetched from a JSON file, using the `*ngFor` directive, it does so by using a service to get the actual data. Here's the code for the component in question:

`operation-catalogue.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { OperationService } from "./operation.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'operation-catalogue-component',
  templateUrl: './operation-catalogue.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./operation-catalogue.component.css'],
})
export class OperationCatalogueComponent implements OnInit {

  operationCatalogue = [];

  constructor(private operationService: OperationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      //Get the items to put in the list...
      this.operationCatalogue = this.operationService.getOperations();
  }
}
```

`operation-catalogue.component.html`:

```
<div id="search-box-div">
    <div id="search-field" class="top-div">
        <input #input type="text" placeholder="Filter">
    </div>
</div>
<ul>
    <!-- generate list, name only -->
    <li *ngFor="let operation of operationCatalogue">
        <label>{{operation.name}}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've left out the service on purpose because it works as intended and not needed for this example.

What I want to do is be able to filter the list that is generated using the html `input` element.

I've tried to have a look at past questions here on stack overflow but they all seem to be outdated and using methods that Angular2 no longer supports.

How can I accomplish this goal with a modern method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use a [Pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) for this. [Here](https://gist.github.com/joejordanbrown/6fca2b0db0450a84b923bcea33ed9ad0) is an example I've created a gist on Github since it's rather long.

operation-catalogue.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { OperationService } from "./operation.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'operation-catalogue-component',
  templateUrl: './operation-catalogue.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./operation-catalogue.component.css'],
})
export class OperationCatalogueComponent implements OnInit {

  operationCatalogue = [];
  objectsFilter = {name: ''};

  constructor(private operationService: OperationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      //Get the items to put in the list...
      this.operationCatalogue = this.operationService.getOperations();
  }
}
```

operation-catalogue.component.html:

```
<div id="search-box-div">
    <div id="search-field" class="top-div">
        <input #input type="text" placeholder="Filter" [(ngModel)]="objectsFilter.name">
    </div>
</div>
<ul>
    <!-- generate list, name only -->
    <li *ngFor="let operation of operationCatalogue | filterBy: {name: objectsFilter.name};">
        <label>{{operation.name}}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Plunker example:
https://embed.plnkr.co/xbW6nbkQZfwudOAnrEXl/

Comment: is the `filterDefault` function necessary? At this point in time I'm only interested in filtering by a string (in this case the name, `{{operation.name}}`)

Comment: @PythonNewb you can simplify the Pipe that I've supplied you with, it is an all round filter pipe that can be used for more advanced use cases also where you'd want to filter more than one object key.

Comment: I see. So for my basic use case I only really need to use the `filterByString()` method

Comment: I think you have a misplaced quote mark in this line `<input #input type="text" placeholder="Filter [(ngModel)]="objectsFilter.name">`, the list is not rendering for me at all

Comment: I've fixed that now, but `[(ngModel)]="objectsFilter.name"` gives me an error "cannot read property name of undefined"

Comment: Yes I see that I'll correct that in the answer. Have you set the objectsFilter variable with the object inside of your using that variable inside the pipe?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. I tried replacing `objectsFilter.name` with `operation.name` which is my local variable but it does not work

Comment: I will create a plunker :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130369/discussion-between-j-j-b-and-pythonnewb).

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf feature of Angular2+,

```
<li *ngIf="searchElement === '' || (label |  lowercase).indexOf(searchElement |  lowercase) != -1" >
```

This will work without any extra pipe. indexOf will return any number if it found match text.